# Best way to rebase atop a repo with many moved files?

Tags: git, rebase

I have two branches A and B.

I started from the position where Branch B is about 200 commits ahead of Branch A.

In the mean time, many files in Branch A have been moved, for example the Java files from `src/org/**` were moved to into to `module1/src/main/java/org/**` and the non-Java files to `module1/src/main/resources/**`.

I have a list of all the moved folders and files.

I would like to rebase Branch B atop Branch A. Typically I would do something like:

```
git fetch upstream && git checkout B && git rebase upstream/A
```

However, this doesn't apply cleanly as Branch B both adds new files and modifies existing files in `src/org`, but some of these have been moved (with `git mv`) in Branch A.

Is there a way where I can tell git about all the moved paths when it does a rebase, e.g. when you create a new file in `src/org`, instead now create it in `module1/src/main/java/org`?

Or would the best approach be to create a large patch set from Branch B using `git format-patch`, then do a find and replace in all the patch files to update the paths, before applying them to a new branch of A?

Or perhaps there is another way entirely?

Comment: Afaik Git doesn’t know about moved paths, but it does makes guesses based on content similarity.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I did:

1. git checkout B
2. git format-patch -o patches/ HEAD~198
3. A whole load of Sed against the patches
4. git checkout A
5. git checkout -b new-B
6. git am -3 patches/*

It was relatively painless, shame there isn't a better way by combining rebase/filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you try `git checkout a && git rebase b` you are getting files where git gets confused, right?

In order to minimize the times when git gets confused because of renaming while keeping both branches... I think I would try a double cycle... in fact, it's even one idea for a nice git script.... say that A is the diversion point between B and C... say there are 5 revisions between A and B and 20 between A and C.

Instead of rebasing C on top of B, I would first base on top of B~4, then rebase the resulting branch on top of B~3, then again on top of B~2, then B~1, finally on top of B. It's redoing a lot of work, but probably git will get less confused when trying to *match* the files that you moved around.... and rebases normally are done faster than snapping your fingers so it shouldn't be too painful.